# In "acts-as-taggable-on", how to get all the tags used in all the instances of a Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I have my model class described like this:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

How to get all the `tags` used by any instance of this model class?

I tried:

```
MyModel.tags_on(:tags).pluck(:name)
```

and it works but it generates a query that includes the ids of all the instances of my model:

```sql
SELECT tags.* FROM `tags` JOIN (SELECT `taggings`.`tag_id` FROM `taggings` WHERE (taggings.taggable_type = 'MyModel') AND (taggings.taggable_id IN ( **[ALL THE IDS]** ) GROUP BY `taggings`.`tag_id`) AS taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id
```

Same with:

```
MyModel.all_tags.pluck(:name)
```

I also have tried:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.for_context(:tags).pluck(:name)
```

But it returns all the `tags` in the context `tags` for all the models classes and not only `MyModel` class

Comment: The problem here is that the join is missing  `taggings.taggable_type = "MyModel"`. If this is a bug or the indented behavior is kind of unclear though as its not that well documented. I personally avoid any of the gems where the name starts with "acts".

Comment: @max what do you use to manage tagging?

Comment: Two models. If you don't need to be able to add taxonomies to a bunch of different models the tradeoffs of a polymorphic swiss-army-bulldozer approach doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is to just take one of the queries that's returning all tags and refine it to just your `taggable_type`:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.for_context(:tags).where(taggings: { taggable_type: 'MyModel'}).uniq.pluck(:name)
```

Comment: @fguillen see the edited version and let me know if that works. The taggable_type column is presumably on the `taggings` table, so I needed to specify that in the `where` condition as a scoped condition.

Comment: It works now :). I added `.uniq` to remove duplicates. The query is short and precise. I'm removing my comments to avoid confusion for other readers.